# How to do conditional statements based on SqlQuery results in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt-creator, qsqlquery

What I want to do is to query.exec() a DELETE statement, and if delete is successful I want to display the updated table, else display a QMessageBox saying that the name did not match.

I was under the impression that if DELETE statement does not find an entry, query.exec() will be FALSE. But it is always true no matter what I enter for the name. Is there a work around this problem? Thanks all...

So the code I currently have is:

```
bool ok;
QInputDialog *dialog = new QInputDialog;
QString name = dialog->getText((QWidget*)this->parent(), tr("Enter Buyer to Delete:"),
                                          tr("Buyer Name:"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                                          "", &ok);
QSqlTableModel *model1;
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("DELETE from buyers WHERE name=:name");
query.addBindValue(name);
bool x = query.exec();      //<----PROBLEM: EVEN WITH INCORRECT name,
qDebug() << x;              // query.exec() RETURNS true ALTHOUGH delete
if (!x)                     // IS SUPPOSED TO FAIL 
{
    QMessageBox box;
    box.setInformativeText("No buyer found with name matching " + name);
    box.exec();

}
model1 = new QSqlTableModel;
model1->setTable("buyers");
model1->select();

model1->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ID"));
model1->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
model1->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Location"));
model1->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Phone"));
model1->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Email"));

QTableView *view1 = new QTableView;
view1->setWindowTitle("Buyer List updated");
view1->setModel(model1);
view1->show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QSqlQuery::​numRowsAffected()`:

```
QSqlQuery query("your_query_here");
query.exec();
if(query.numRowsAffected() == 0)
{
    //didn't delete anything
}
else
{
    //worked fine
}
```

Note, that per Qt docs, this function

> Returns the number of rows affected by the result's SQL statement, or
>   -1 if it cannot be determined. Note that for SELECT statements, the value is undefined; use size() instead. If the query is not active, -1
>   is returned.